# Return pieces of strings from separate pandas dataframes based on multi-conditional logic

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm new to python, and trying to do some work with dataframes in pandas

On the left side is piece of the primary dataframe (df1), and the right is a second (df2).  The goal is to fill in the df1['vd_type'] column with strings based on several pieces of conditional logic.  I can make this work with nested np.where() functions, but as this gets deeper into the hierarchy, it gets too long to run at all, so I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

The english version of the logic is this:
For df1['vd_type']: If df1['shape'] == the first two characters in df2['vd_combo'] AND df1['vd_pct'] <= df2['combo_value'], then return the last 3 characters in df2['vd_combo'] on the line where both of these conditions are true.  If it can't find a line in df2 where both conditions are true, then return "vd4".

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT #2:  So I want to implement a 3rd condition based on another variable, with everything else the same, except in df1 there is another column 'log_vsc' with existing values, and the goal is to fill in an empty df1 column 'vsc_type' with one of 4 strings in the same scheme.  The extra condition would be just that the 'vd_type' that we just defined would match the 'vd' column arising from the split 'vsc_combo'.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['vsc_combo'] = ['A1_vd1_vsc1','A1_vd1_vsc2','A1_vd1_vsc3','A1_vd2_vsc1','A1_vd2_vsc2' etc etc etc
df3['combo_value'] = [(number), (number), (number), (number), (number), etc etc

df3[['shape','vd','vsc']] = df3['vsc_combo'].str.split('_', expand = True)

def vsc_condition( row, df3):
    df_select = df3[(df3['shape'] == row['shape']) & (df3['vd'] == row['vd_type']) & (row['log_vsc'] <= df3['combo_value'])]
    if df_select.empty:
        return 'vsc4'
    else:
        return df_select['vsc'].iloc[0]

## apply vsc_type
df1['vsc_type'] = df1.apply( vsc_condition, args = ([df3]), axis = 1)
```

And this works!! Thanks again!

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/UZGns77OMHc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so your inputs are like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'shape': ['A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'A2'],
                    'vd_pct': [0.78, 0.33, 0.48, 0.38, 0.59]} )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vd_combo': ['A1_vd1', 'A1_vd2', 'A1_vd3', 'A2_vd1', 'A2_vd2', 'A2_vd3', 'B1_vd1', 'B1_vd2', 'B1_vd3'],
                    'combo_value':[0.38, 0.56, 0.68, 0.42, 0.58, 0.71, 0.39, 0.57, 0.69]} )
```

If you are not against creating columns in df2 (you can delete them at the end if it's a problem) you generate two columns `shape` and `vd` by splitting the column `vd_combo`:

```
df2[['shape','vd']] = df2['vd_combo'].str.split('_',expand=True)
```

Then you can create a function `condition` that you will use in `apply` such as:

```
def condition( row, df2):
   # row will be a row of df1 in apply
   # here you select only the rows of df2 with your conditions on shape and value
   df_select = df2[(df2['shape'] == row['shape']) & (row['vd_pct'] <= df2['combo_value'])]
   # if empty (your condition not met) then return vd4
   if df_select.empty:
       return 'vd4'
   # if your condition met, then return the value of 'vd' the smallest
   else:
       return df_select['vd'].iloc[0]
```

Now you can create your column `vd_type` in `df1` with:

```
df1['vd_type'] = df1.apply( condition, args =([df2]), axis=1)
```

`df1` is like:

```
  shape  vd_pct vd_type
0    A2    0.78     vd4
1    A1    0.33     vd1
2    B1    0.48     vd2
3    B1    0.38     vd1
4    A2    0.59     vd3
```